# how to pass value from views to non-editable field django python

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i want to auto insert user to the follwing model:

```
class Moduls(models.Model):
    module_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, db_column='created_by', blank=False, null=False , on_delete=models.CASCADE,  editable = False)
```

i have 2 cases :
1- in django admin and i solve this case by the following
* add editable = False to created by field
* in admin.py i used the follwoing:

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

      obj.created_by = request.user
      super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

but i face the problem when i try to use forms.py i can't pass user from user views.py and if i want to add created_by field to my form i have this error:

'created_by' cannot be specified for Moduls model form as it is a non-editable field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally do *not* set that in the form, but in the view. So you define a form that looks like:

```
class ModulsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Moduls
        fields = ['module_name']
```

In the view, you then set the `created_by` field of the instance wrapped in the view. So for a function-based view, it looks like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModulsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.created_by = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = ModulsForm()
    return render(request, 'name-of-some-template.html', {'form': form})
```

or in a class-based view, for example a `CreateView`, you override the `form_valid` method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class ModulsCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Moduls
    form_class = ModulsForm
    # …

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: the above solved my problem. but could you please tell me what is the important of instance because i made this solution without instance not work but after i add instance it's working fine